# How to insert values in database from dynamically loaded controls using C#

Tags: c#, windows

I have table like below:

```
Status  userID  SysID  SysCode
  1      1       1      A
  0      1       1      B   
  0      1       1      C
  1      1       2      A
  1      1       2      B
  0      1       2      C
```

I have 10 systems and for every each set of system 3 systemcodes are there. I am able to populate the systems in the table but unable to insert the systemcode, we can hardcode the systemcode as these are standard. All controls are dynamically loaded controls.

I am doing:

```
// to get SystemID

if (readerLocalSystem.HasRows)
{
    while (readerLocalSystem.Read())
    {
        UserAccessSystemID = Convert.ToInt32(readerLocalSystem["LocalSystemID"]);
                                        MessageBox.Show(i.ToString());
    }
}

//to insert into table
if (cb.Checked == true)
{
    localSystemBranchStatus = 1;
}
else
{
    localSystemBranchStatus = 0;
}

string strLocalSysBranch = "insert into LocalSystemBranch (BranchStatus, UserProfileId,LLocalSystemId, SystemCode) values('" + BranchStatus + "','" + UserProfileID + "','" + SystemID + "','" + BranchCode + "')";
```

How to insert the SystemCode?

Comment: I can't understand your question at all, but a wild guess is that you are putting single quotes around integer values in your sql and that is an error.

Comment: Iam not getting any error,but i am unable to get the systemcode based on the table i have

Comment: You are showing the assignment of two variables that are not used in your sql anywhere, so why show it? How do you set `BranchCode`?

Comment: To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].